# Python list unpacking, is this expensive? Is it inefficient?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a Python function that returns multiple elements, for example `myfoo0()`

```
def myfoo0():
   return([1, 2, 3])
```

and that this is used as:

```
fit = myfoo0();
```

Now, consider a function that used some of the entries of `fit` as input. For example:

```
def myfoo1(fit):
   [a, b, c] = fit
   return(doSomething(a))
```

Now, I find it easier to read the intend if I write this as:

```
fit = myfoo0();
out = myfoo1(fit)
```

(an example is when I have many functions `myfoo1`,...,`myfoon` each using different components of `fit`)
my question is how does the above code (with a naming of the entries of `fit` inside the body of `myfoo1`) compares (from a performance point of view) to this one:

```
[a, b, c] = myfoo0();
out = myfoo2(a)
```

where

```
def myfoo2(a):
   return(doSomething(a))
```

In particular, is the solution with tuple unpacking inside the function incur a significant additional cost (for example in terms of copying)?

Comment: You're not making deep copies anywhere.  Any copies here are shallow.  But in this case, it's a moot point since you never have more than one level of list (or other object) nesting, in which case deep and shallow copies are equivalent.  And example of a deep copy would be if you have a list of lists, and all of the lists at both levels are copied.  A shallow copy would only copy the top-level list, with the nested lists being shared.

Comment: It's just the same.

Comment: Ok, removed the mention to deep copies which I had misunderstood what they meant in this context. My question is: is the first construct somehow inefficient --am I incurring a cost for the (IMHO) added clarity?

Comment: First a clarification:  In this example, you're unpacking a list, not a tuple.  A tuple is an immutable list, and is delimited by parentheses rather than square brackets.  `[1, 2, 3]` is a list.  `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple.  Second, the performance of your two examples should be comparable.  In both cases, `myfoo1` is constructing a list and returning it.  Then in one case, the list is passed to a function which unpacks it, and in the other cases the caller unpacks it and passes one of the values to a function.  The amount of work being done in both cases is essentially the same.

Comment: @TomKarzes: thanks: fixed `tuple` to be `list`

Comment: Why would there be any performance difference in both the cases ? Essentially they are doing the same thing .

Comment: It depends on the language! Now I know in Python they are. Some other language could have done additional copies~

Comment: If any language keeps making copies, the performance would be pretty bad.Do you know any such language ?

Comment: I am not sure, I think R would make copies (but the language tries to prevent you from making such constructs). Matlab has a similar construct but I don't know if it makes copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some misconceptions here:

1. `fit = myfoo0();` doesn't copy anything. `fit` is merely a reference to the list returned by `myfoo0()`, not a copy.
2. `[a, b, c] = myfoo0();` doesn't create a new list as well. On the otherhand, you have 3 variables being references to the first, second and third list members respectively.
3. `out = myfoo1(fit)` is not the same `myfoo1(a)`. The first call invokes myfoo1 with a list passed as first argument, the second call invokes myfoo1 with the first list member passed as first argument.

Comment: Sorry, please have a look at the edited question: reading your answer I realized I had accidentally deleted part of the question during an unfortunate edit~

Comment: @user189035 Sorry your question in the current state is quite confusing. Why would you expect that the two snippets perform differently? They are exactly the same except if you assume that global vs local variable access time is different (which might be) and this is such an scenario. Even then we are talking about such an infinitesmall difference that unless this is the most critical part of you most time consuming algorithm, you probably won't even be able to measure a notable difference. Talking about premature optimization...

Comment: @Sebastien Hoffmann: you have answered my question in your comment "the difference between the two syntaxes in terms of performance is negligible"